# Switch between Entity Framework read only and read write replica based on API request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API. I have two databases with exactly same schema, one is read only and other is read write.

What would be the best approach to switch between the two databases, based on incoming requests?

I need to switch to read-only database when I am fetching some data.
In all other requests I need to use read write database.

I have UOW implemented too.

Comment: You can create two API controllers, in one controller you do actions to read-only database  for fetching some data. In another controller, you can do  actions to  read write database  for other needs.